# giant responsive input field text

Tags: jquery, input

I am trying to make an input field with huge text. I would like this text to be maximum size, and then to scale accordingly so that long email addresses do not leave the field of vision.

[HERE](http://derekthomaswood.com/dev/input) is a dev site.

I am working with fittext.js to try and achieve this.

However, I feel like I have seen this somewhere before and it was not as complicatied as I feel I am making it.

Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the input to a monospace font, you could conceivably put a listener on the keyup event, get the length in characters of the input, then calculate how small the font size should be in order for the value to fit on one line.

```
var input = $("input");
input.on("keyup",function(evt){

    var char_count = input.val().length;
    var input_width = input.width();
    var new_font_size = Math.floor( input_width / char_count );
    input.css("fontSize",new_font_size+"px");

});​
```

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G2dh4/).

Comment: This is a cool approach. The first 3 letters fall out of view though.

Comment: You could easily enough implement a "max_font_size" variable and set the height of the text input so that it works with that large font. I figured I'd leave that to you to refine and improve :P

Answer (score 0):

Fittext doesn't seem to like to be called multiple times. Try this plugin instead: https://github.com/vxsx/jquery.inputfit.js

Then, you can just
`jQuery('.putin').inputfit();`

example: http://jsfiddle.net/BGJjS/

Comment: This one is pretty close. It cuts off some of the letters at certain points. It also doesn't move in reverse. Once the text gets smaller - it stays that way forever. I'll check out this plug-in. thanks.